# In Org mode, what is the priority order for a file's initial visibility?

Tags: org-mode

Three things control an Org mode file's [Initial Visibility](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html): a heading's `VISIBILITY` property, the file's `#+STARTUP:` line, and the `org-startup-folded` variable.

In terms of priority, I've always assumed it was as I've just given -- highest to lowest. That is, I assumed that the folding of any given heading in a newly opened file was determined by the value of:

1. That heading's `VISIBILITY` property, if it has one, else;
2. The file's `#+STARTUP:` line, if it has one, else;
3. The `org-startup-folded` variable (which defaults to 'showeverything')

and in general that does seem to be the case.

However, there appears to be an exception where if the value prior to taking the `VISIBILITY` property into account is `showeverything`, then the `VISIBILITY` properties of all headings are simply ignored. That could matter if, for example, you wanted all headings to be fully unfolded, except for one or two. That cannot be done by having a general setting of `showeverything` and then using `VISIBILITY` to override for the few headings you want folded, because `VISIBILITY` simply *cannot* override a value of `showeverything`.

Now it's not a massive issue because, in the above example say, `showall` could be used instead of `showeverything`. Unlike `showeverything`, `showall` *can* be overriden by `VISIBILITY`. (And in fact `showall` may even be preferable because it, unlike `showeverything`, doesn't open up drawers).

Still, it feels like it might be a wee bug.

**Is it? Or is there a reason that the current behavior makes sense?**

Comment: It seems to be deliberate: see [l.631 of org-cycle.el](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-cycle.el#n631). I'm guessing that it is an attempt to protect new users from unpleasant surprises - the same reason that was used to justify changing the default value of `org-startup-folded` from `t` to `showeverything`.